# Not able to get the output in NIO

Tags: java, nio

I want the program to give me an echo back when i type something, i don't get any errors but it doesn't work, it connects properly but i don't receive anything back when i type in the server

```
private static Selector selector;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    selector = Selector.open();
    ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ssc.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080));
    ssc.configureBlocking(false);
    ssc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    while (true) {
        selector.select();
        for (Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            SelectionKey key = it.next();
            it.remove();
            if (key.isAcceptable())
                acceptRead(key);
            else if (key.isWritable())
                write(key);
        }
    }
}

private static void acceptRead(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
    SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
    System.out.println("Connected with " + sc);
    sc.configureBlocking(false);
    SelectionKey key2 = sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
    sc.read(buf);
    buf.flip();
    key2.attach(buf);
}

private static void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    ByteBuffer buf = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();
    sc.write(buf);
}

}
```

Comment: The [write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#write-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) method isn't guaranteed to write the entire buffer (or anything at all).  Wrap your call to `write` in `while (buf.hasRemaining())`.

Comment: i wrapped "sc.write(buf)" of the last method write inside "while (buf.hasRemaining())" , i still don't have any output

Answer (score 0):

Very strange code here.

- If the key is acceptable you should call `accept()` on the channel.
- If the key is *readable* you should call `read()` on the channel.
- If you get -1 from `read()` you must close the channel.
- After you write you must `compact()` the buffer, and surely you want to register the channel for `OP_READ` again?